# Can we write this in general for calculating double (or triple) integrals?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This is a relation which seems to make sense but I couldn't find anything on google.

$$\int^a_b \int^c_d \alpha f(x)g(y)~dxdy= \alpha \int^a_b g(y)dy\int^c_d f(x)dx$$

It just seems less likely to make mistakes when splitting the integrals like this as you don't have to even think about $y$ when integrating w.r.t $x$. The only caveat I can think of is if instead of constant limits of integration we have maybe a function of $x$ or $y$ in the limits of integration then presumably we have to follow whatever order of integration is needed to compute the integral?

Thanks.

Comment: Keywords: Fubini's Theorem

Comment: Hint: you can always move a constant factor into the integral.

Comment: [Exactly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem). If the double integral of the absolute value exists, you just integrate twice, then one factor is a constant for the internal integral so you carry it out, and now the internal integral is a constant, so you take _that_ out to get a product of integrals.